# How to access item inside list using singleWhere.. flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm using `singleWhere` to check if the item already exists inside a list in flutter, but I can't access this item inside the logic, here is my code :

```dart
if ((invoiceAdditionsList.singleWhere((it) => it.realID == invoiceAdditionInstance.realID,
   orElse: () => null)) !=
   null) {
      print('Already exists! $it');
      } else {
      print('not there');
        }
```

In the line `print('Already exists! $it');` is the error, it can't access it here.

Comment: Could you please try with [indexWhere](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/indexWhere.html) and let me know if that works for you?

Comment: What type is the `realID` property?

Comment: @MiguelRuivo double

Comment: @AhmedWagdi I suspect you may have different precisions on both values. This is, `10.013` will return false when compared with `10.0134`. Make sure you have both doubles with the same precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the item, and get it stored as per the result. Since `singleWhere()` gives out the single existing item, else throws error. Do something like this, and  let me know if that works out

```
var item = invoiceAdditionsList.singleWhere((it) => it.realID == invoiceAdditionInstance.realID, orElse: () => null); 

// and later check that element out
print("Element found $item" ?? "Not there")
```

If your concerned about getting the first found element only from the list, you can consider using [firstWhere()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html), cos `singleWhere()` throws error when found there is a duplicate or no elements found. Same code, just `firstWhere()`

```
var item = invoiceAdditionsList.firstWhere((it) => it.realID == invoiceAdditionInstance.realID, orElse: () => null);

print("Element found: $item" ?? "Not there");
```

This is just the dummy code for you, to understand it better, using `singleWhere()`

```
void main() {
  List testIndex = [1,3,4,5,6,78,80];
  
  var item = testIndex.singleWhere((it) => it == 120, orElse: () => null); 
  print(item ?? "No item found"); // No item found
}
```